# Searching for com.ibm.xsp.sbtsdk.playground.library

Tags: xpages, ibm-connections, opensocial

I have installed the openSocial Business Toolkit from the IBM.
Everytime after all packages installed on my server and the client the com.ibm.xsp.sbtsdk.playground.library is missing.
I haven't got found it on any site or version of the toolkit.
In the version
sbtsdk-1.0.3.20140723-1200 its missing and also in the
sbtsdk-1.0.0.20121203-1053 its missing.

I have install the packages from
sbtsdk-1.0.3.20140723-1200\sbtsdk\redist\domino
like its stands in the documentation from
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/dx/Installing_the_SDK_Playground_SDK1.0

Does anyone have an idea where I can become the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/releases 
In the download sbtsdk-VERSION.zip, navigate to sbtsdk\redist\domino  it's in the feature site com.ibm.sbt.domino.playground.updatesite-VERSION.zip

it'll be in that file